# Search input by letter? indexOf maybe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
this.state = {
  text: ''
};

onChange(e) {
this.setState({text: e.target.value});
};

render() {
const { selectRate } = this.props.selectRate;
const { errors, click } = this.state;

//Filter Rate(s)
let arr = [];
if (!isEmpty(selectRate)) {
  for (let i = 0; i < selectRate.length; i++) {
    const element = selectRate[i];
    arr.push({ id: i, name: element })
  }
}
```

console.log(arr)
returns

```
  10: {id: 10, name: "PHP"}
  11: {id: 11, name: "HRK"}
  12: {id: 12, name: "NOK"}
  13: {id: 13, name: "ZAR"}
  14: {id: 14, name: "MXN"}
  15: {id: 15, name: "AUD"}
  16: {id: 16, name: "USD"}

const list = arr.filter(search(this.state.text)).map(i => <option key={i.name}>{i.name}</option>)

return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <input
        autoComplete='off'
        type='search'
        list='list'
        name='text'
        value={this.state.text}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        error = {errors}
      />
      <datalist id='list'>
        {list}
      </datalist>
      <button
        type='submit'
        >Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
)
}
}

export default SearchBar;

function search(a) {
  return function(b) {
  return b.name.toUpperCase().includes(a.toUpperCase()) || !a;
  }
}
```

it returns all "strings" that includes from what you enter in input..
i cant understand how to make to return only the first letter
ex:
if you type U should return only the "strings" that starts with U not that have U inside them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `search` function currently does:

```
return b.name.toUpperCase().includes(a.toUpperCase()) || !a;
```

Sounds like all you need to do is change the `includes` test (which checks whether the string is contained anywhere) to a `startsWith` test (which checks whether the haystack *starts with* the needle):

```
return b.name.toUpperCase().startsWith(a.toUpperCase()) || !a;
```

Note that `startsWith` is an ES6 function, to support older browsers, use a polyfill or `indexOf` instead:

```
return b.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(a.toUpperCase()) === 0 || !a;
```

Because you're already using ES6 syntax, you can make the `search` function significantly more concise by using arrow functions and implicit return:

```
const search = a => b => b.name.toUpperCase().startsWith(a.toUpperCase()) || !a;
```